# MySQL how to strip out junk or corrupt characters?

Tags: mysql, validation, etl, corrupt-data

MySQL 5.6

Rows 1-3 seem to have some junk characters.  Row 4 is good data.

```
select id, firstname, length(firstname) len,
substring(firstname,1,1) ss1, ascii(substring(firstname,1,1)) a1,
substring(firstname,2,1) ss2, ascii(substring(firstname,2,1)) a2,
substring(firstname,3,1) ss3, ascii(substring(firstname,3,1)) a3,
substring(firstname,4,1) ss4, ascii(substring(firstname,4,1)) a4,
substring(firstname,5,1) ss5, ascii(substring(firstname,5,1)) a5,
substring(firstname,6,1) ss6, ascii(substring(firstname,6,1)) a6,
substring(firstname,7,1) ss7, ascii(substring(firstname,7,1)) a7,
substring(firstname,8,1) ss8, ascii(substring(firstname,8,1)) a8,
substring(firstname,9,1) ss9, ascii(substring(firstname,9,1)) a9
from users
where id in (91788, 91844, 79631, 5351791)
order by id
```

Results:

[image]

The odd characters are causing problems in an ETL process.  How can I strip out the junk characters?

PS note that row 2 says length 5, but only the first 3 characters have an ascii value.  Is this normal?

Comment: What character set are the columns?

Comment: CHARACTER_SET_NAME utf8

Comment: Are you sure that's what the columns have, too? Tables and columns can have different character sets. Where does the data come from? That looks like Unicode columns with non-Unicode characters in them. Might be worth finding the source of the problem (if there is one)

Comment: SELECT character_set_name 
FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE table_name = "users"
  AND column_name = "firstname";  Result: utf8

Comment: OK. Where does the data come from? Is it broken in the original table already, or just in your query?